# MVC: twelve figures in a model or twelve calls from view?

Tags: java, swing

The task is to show 12 different figures (randomly shaped).

The dilemma is:

1. I can keep the 12 figures in the model. This seems to be preferrable to me as in my opinion looks more like classic MVC. A view will just represent what is inside the model.
2. In the model we can create a method to return a new figure. Then a view just contains a loop which calls for a new figure 12 times. What troubles me is that this case seems to be a violation of MVC principles.

As for where it all be applied to:

1. Swing right now;
2. web applications in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can keep the 12 figures in the model.

This would be the way all other Swing components work like JTable, JList , JTextField

> 2.In the model we can create a method to return a new figure

A model is generally not used to create data, only store the data.